# How to transform your data and to create a heatmap with geom_tile?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, ggplot2

I have a data frame with 60 rows (or 60 cases that represent work schedules) and 672 columns that represent time steps. Time is measured for 7 days (starting with Monday) in 15 minutes intervals and it starts at 04:00 and ends at 03:45.

The structure of the data frame representing 4 days:

```
dput(head(TiNiSWeek,4))
structure(list(`04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 
2, 0, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `17:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(2, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(2, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(2, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(2, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(2, 
0, 2, 0), `08:15` = c(2, 0, 2, 0), `08:30` = c(2, 0, 2, 0), `08:45` = c(2, 
0, 2, 0), `09:00` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `09:15` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `09:30` = c(2, 
2, 2, 0), `09:45` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `10:00` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `10:45` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `11:30` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(2, 2, 0, 2), `12:15` = c(2, 2, 0, 2), `12:30` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `13:00` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `13:45` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `14:30` = c(2, 2, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `15:15` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `15:30` = c(2, 
2, 2, 0), `15:45` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `16:00` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `16:15` = c(2, 
2, 2, 0), `16:30` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `16:45` = c(2, 2, 2, 0), `17:00` = c(2, 
2, 2, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 
2, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 
2, 0, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `15:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 0), `15:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `16:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `17:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 2, 0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 
2, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `17:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 2, 2), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 2, 2), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `09:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 
2, 2, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 2), `17:45` = c(0, 
2, 0, 2), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 2), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `10:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `10:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `10:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `11:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `11:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `11:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `11:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `12:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `12:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `12:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `12:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `13:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `13:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `13:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `14:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `14:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `14:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `15:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `15:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `15:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `15:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `16:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `16:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `16:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `10:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `10:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `10:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `11:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `11:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `11:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `11:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `12:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `12:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `12:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `12:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `13:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `13:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `13:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `14:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `14:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `14:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `15:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `15:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `15:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `15:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `16:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `16:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `16:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below an example of a data frame with 10 observations for 3 days staring at 04:00 and ending 03:45

```
     04:00 04:15...03:45 04:00 04:15...03:45 04:00 04:15...03:45
 1:     0     0      0     0      0      2        2    0        2
 2:     2     2      0     2      2      2        0    0        0
 3:     2     0      2     2      2      2        0    2        2
 4:     0     0      0     2      2      2        0    2        2
 5:     0     0      0     2      2      2        0    2        2
 6:     2     0      2     0      2      2        0    2        2
 7:     0     0      0     2      2      2        2    0        2
 8:     2     2      2     2      2      2        0    0        2
 9:     0     0      0     2      2      2        0    0        2
10:     2     2      2     2      2      2        0    0        2
```

My first question is how to transform the data to show the daily work schedules; in other words the first observation starting at 04:00 and end ending at 03:45 to show the Monday schedules; followed by 04:00 and end ending at 03:45 to show the Tuesday schedules.

```
          Monday                    Tuesday            Wednesday  
      04:00 04:15...03:45   04:00 04:15...03:45   04:00 04:15...03:45
 1:     0     0      0        0      0      2        2    0        2
 2:     2     2      0        2      2      2        0    0        0
 3:     2     0      2        2      2      2        0    2        2
 4:     0     0      0        2      2      2        0    2        2
 5:     0     0      0        2      2      2        0    2        2
 6:     2     0      2        0      2      2        0    2        2
 7:     0     0      0        2      2      2        2    0        2
 8:     2     2      2        2      2      2        0    0        2
 9:     0     0      0        2      2      2        0    0        2
10:     2     2      2        2      2      2        0    0        2
```

In the next step I want to extract the beginning and the ending of the intervals starting with '2'

For example 2: Monday:  04:00-04:15; 
               Tuesday: 04:00-04:15;

Finally I would like to transform the data and to plot the starting and ending of the intervals with geom_tile similarly as image below:

Based on the above answer + my work the improved plot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would go about this. I've put the output of your `dput` statement in a variable named `df`.

First I'd rename your colnames to include the day of the week:

```
df2 <- df
weekdays <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
colnames(df2) <- paste0(rep(weekdays, each = 24 * 4), "_", colnames(df2))
```

Then I add an index to each row, so it can be used as the y-axis.

```
df2$index <- 1:nrow(df2)
```

Then I melt the data from a wide format to a long format and set what were our colnames to a character instead of factor:

```
df3 <- reshape2::melt(df2, id.vars = "index")
df3$variable <- as.character(df3$variable)
```

The former colnames need now to be interpreted again as day + time. I set the day as a factor following the `weekdays` order. I set the time variable as a continuous `hour + minutes / 60`.

```
df3$day <- sapply(strsplit(df3$variable, "_"), `[`, 1)
df3$day <- factor(df3$day, levels = weekdays)
df3$time <- sapply(strsplit(df3$variable, "_"), `[`, 2)
df3$time <- as.numeric(substr(df3$time, 1, 2)) + as.numeric(substr(df3$time, 4, 5)) / 60
```

Then we can plot this as a raster with days as facets:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x = time, y = index, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  facet_grid(~ day) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), name = "Hour") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

Which comes pretty close to the heatmap you were proposing.

Finally for extracting the invervals for an index `i`:

```
library(S4Vectors)
i <- 4
rle <- Rle(as.numeric(df[i,]))
ends <- end(rle)
starts <- start(rle)
out <- data.frame(length = rle@lengths, 
                  values = rle@values, 
                  start = starts, 
                  end = ends)
head(out)
```

```
  length values start end
1     24      0     1  24
2     32      2    25  56
3     64      0    57 120
4     20      2   121 140
5     76      0   141 216
6     20      2   217 236
```

Which you can convert to times as follows:

```
colnames(df)[out$start[out$values == 2]]
```

```
[1] "10:00" "10:00" "10:00" "09:45" "09:30"
```

EDIT: You can convert the continuous time representation back to a clock like format by using this function as `labels` inside `scale_x_continuous/discrete()`:

```
timeformat <- function(x){
  # Get back relevant numbers
  unshift <- ifelse(x > 24, x - 24, x)
  hours <- unshift - unshift %% 1
  minutes <- (unshift - hours) * 60

  # Format
  hour <- formatC(hour, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
  minutes <- formatC(minutes, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")

  return(paste0(hour,":", minutes))
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help and detailed advise. One more question I am struggling to set the time to show 04:00 start and 03:45 end, is think I need to use the is.interval() function?

Comment: You can add 24 hours to everything under 4 hours: `df3$time <- ifelse(df3$time < 4, df3$time + 24, df3$time)`, you just need to adjust the labels on the x-axis accordingly.

Comment: thank you but for 2 hours I am trying to adjust the x axis and still not working? How to set to adjust the x axis  with geom_raster?

Comment: You would probably need a function for the `label =` statement in `scale_x_continuous/discrete()`. Something like the following: `scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x){ifelse(x > 24, x - 24, x)})`

Comment: thank you for your kindness I would never figure out that - one more question - if you have time - how can adjust time to show hours and minutes so like 10:00 ? tahnks

Comment: I added a function to do this to my answer, hope it helps!